# How big is Stack Exchange iOS ß?

Tags: support, ios-app

Pretty simple question: What is the overall size of the Stack Exchange iOS Beta app? I'm trying to install the app on my iPhone but I fear the file size will use up my mobile data usage limit.

Comment: Pretty simple solution: Download over Wi-Fi? Not trying to be super snarky but... is there a reason to not simply wait until you have Wi-Fi access somewhere to download it? No reason to use up your data on a download.

Comment: True, but I'm quite curious XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last build was 28.56MB. Basically as expensive as [visiting The Verge 3 times](http://blog.lmorchard.com/2015/07/22/the-verge-web-sucks/).